# What is a good workflow to draw an irradiance distribution of a lamp? A cone with a light-like look is the goal

Tags: python, texturing, shaders, vertex-colors

I would like to draw a distribution of irradiance of a light. The plan that I went about is to generate a heat map independent of Blender. So I have a csv file that has a heat map containing the irradiance value at different points in space. How can I draw up a cone that has that as a color gradient equal to the reduction of irradiance as shown in the csv file with respect to distance?